# Using the google calendar api libraries with django The sendNotification parameter does not send notification mails to an event's guests

Tags: python, django, notifications, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar API library with django.
creating or updating an event with the request parameter "sendNotification" set to True, the guests included in the event do not receive any notification via email.

This is the code :

```
created_event = service.events().update(calendarId=calendar_id,sendNotifications=True, eventId=event_id, body=modified_event).execute()
```

the Notification setting in the calendars are correct ( enabled , and Email type is selected )

I'm using a service account for authentication, I do not know if it can affect

thanks for the support

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you ever figure out what the issue was? I think something might be broken with the API because it doesn't even work with the API explorer, but maybe I'm wrong